# Warning about assigning to id<UITextFieldDelegate> when I'm conforming to the protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

My view controller is conforming to UITextFieldDelegate, yet when I try and set the .delegate field of my text field to self, I get the warning:

> "Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'AddReviewViewController *const __strong'"

My header file is this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddReviewViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) int storeID;

@end
```

So as you can see, I have it declared to conform to the protocol. In the .m file, I have this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *reviewTextView;
```

in the section "@interface AddReviewViewController ()"

Then, in viewDidLoad I do:

```
_reviewTextView.delegate = self;
```

That's where I get the warning. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, and restarting XCode. Am I missing something obvious here? I'm conforming to the protocol....

EDIT: Thanks for the quick help. In my sleep deprived state I kept re-reading things and swore that's what I was doing but yup, typo. I can't mark an answer for a few minutes, but problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your header you have `UITextFieldDelegate`
And then you declare `UITextView`. There's a big difference between those two.

Edit

```
@interface AddReviewViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

to

```
@interface AddReviewViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe It should be `UITextViewDelegate` in :

```
@interface AddReviewViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) int storeID;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting such error because of this code:

```
@interface PlaceOrderController : UIViewController <     UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate >

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateForUserDOB;
```

To solve this I have used following:

```
@interface PlaceOrderController : UIViewController < UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate >

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateForUserDOB;
```

Summary : use TextField not TextView