# Getting a warning in iOS8

Tags: objective-c

Warning is:

`"Assining to id<MFmailComposeViewControllerDelegate> from incompatible type   BAOfficeDetailViewController"`

My code is

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@""];
```

Comment: You need to make the "self" class adopt the mail compose delegate.

Comment: @Sunny There is no need to add it in the .h file. Other classes don't need to know that the class deals with the mail composer. Better to add the protocol through a class extension in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to conform the protocol with correct name and in correct place. Please recheck your code. Refer this [how to conform to the protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086721/warning-about-assigning-to-iduitextfielddelegate-when-im-conforming-to-the-pr)